# coset representative proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying coset representatives and I don't understand part of a proof.

To be specific, it's about proving "Any $x \in gH$ is a coset representative"

The proof is

$x \in gH \to g^{-1}x \in H \to x^{-1}g \in H \to g \in xH$ . Where $g \in G$

I don't understand why the third arrow works.

BTW, that's not complete proof.  $H$ is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: Third arrow: $g=x(x^{-1}g)\in xH$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{-1}g\in H\Rightarrow x^{-1}g=h$ for some $h\in H\Rightarrow g=xh$ for some $h\in H\Rightarrow g\in xH$